# MongoDB text indexing array objects columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem that I am trying to text index a document that is a list of documents:

I first insert to DB:

```
db.userlikes.insert({
   "data": [
    {
       "category": "Non-profit organization",
       "name": "Animals"
    },
    {
       "category": "Community",
       "name": "Computers"
    }
   ]
})
```

Then I am trying to create the index for the category column:

```
db.userlikes.ensureIndex({"data.category": "text"})
```

But when I am trying to search I get no results:

```
db.userlikes.find({"data.category": "profit"})
```

**Isn't it possible to index that way? Is the best way is to insert each document in the array ("data") separately? It would be an overhead as I only want to insert to DB responses I get from an API.**

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the documentation concerning text searches](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text).

A text search works like this

```
db.userlikes.find({ $text: {$search:"profit"} })
```

since there can only be one text index per collection (though multiple fields may be indexed).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, I also tried db.userlikes.find({$text: {$search: "profit"}}) but no luck :( I still get no results

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. I created a collection with your sample data, added a text index via `db.userlikes.ensureIndex({"data.category":"text"})` and sent the query `db.userlikes.find({ $text: {$search:"profit"} })`, which gave me the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same steps EA9. And it seems to work for me. You might want to check for any spelling mistakes somewhere. Here is my output with the commands.

```
db.userlikes.insert({
...    "data": [
...     {
...        "category": "Non-profit organization",
...        "name": "Animals"
...     },
...     {
...        "category": "Community",
...        "name": "Computers"
...     }
...    ]
... });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

db.userlikes.find();

{ "_id" : ObjectId("541ff8dc1dca72499395cbcf"), "data" : [ { "category" : "Non-profit organization", "name" : "Animals" }, { "category" : "Community", "name" : "Computers" } ] }


db.userlikes.ensureIndex({"data.category": "text"})


{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}


 db.userlikes.find({ $text: { $search: "profit" } });


{ "_id" : ObjectId("541ff8dc1dca72499395cbcf"), "data" : [ { "category" : "Non-profit organization", "name" : "Animals" }, { "category" : "Community", "name" : "Computers" } ] }
```