# Text indexes MongoDB for Array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Ive browsed around for the solution but none seemed to work in my case

[MongoDB text indexing array objects columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957557/mongodb-text-indexing-array-objects-columns)

[Indexing arrays of objects in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803725/indexing-arrays-of-objects-in-mongodb)

My issue is I have a listing mongoose model where each listing can have many categories, I want to be able to search via category and return all listing associated with those categories.

My model is defined like this

```
let ListingSchema = new Schema({
    categories: [{
        id: {type: Number, required: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        suggestedName: {type: String, required: true},
        link: {type: String, path: true}
    }],
    allergyAdvice: {type: String},
    location: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    vendorId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true},
}, {timestamps: true});

ListingSchema.index({
    alergyAdvice: 'text',
    'categories.name': 'text',
}, {
    weights: {
        'categories.name': 7,
        alergyAdvice: 4,
    },
});

ListingSchema.set('toObject', {getters: true});
ListingSchema.set('toJSON', {getters: true});
```

When it comes to searching for listings with the associated categories I use the following query -

```
const listings = await Listing.find({
                $text: {$search: "Sweet"}
            });
```

The query would work for the alergyAdvice index but not the `categories.name` one and would return an empty array for the listings.

Comment: Can I ask, is it possible in your use case to target the search to `categories.name` field? something like `find({ "categories.name": /sweet/ig })`?

Comment: Just tried this command -   `const listings = await Listing.find({"categories.name": categoryLink});` and returned nothing although in my db that Listing document exists